# Undefined variable error on a variable inside an included file

Tags: php, variables, include, undefined

I'm including this file to collect one of its variables. File path is correct and i don't get file include errors. But when i try to print a variable inside that file it gives undefined variable error. Following is the code.

```
include_once($path . "folder/file.php");
 echo($code);
```

There is a php class. inside the class there is a login function . Within that function I'm including another file assume it's funtions.php.

functions.php has above code in it.

Inside functions.php file i include this file which contains the variable i'm looking for (assume it's test.php).

test.php looks like this (inside php tags)

```
     $code="something";
     $another_variable="something else";
```

so now like i said before when i include this inside functions.php and print $code it why does it gives an undefined error?

**Full code**

```
 function log($user, $pass) {

     global $config;
    $this->get_available_accounts();
    if (isset($this->Users_obj[$user])) {
        if ($this->Users_obj[$user]->userName == $user && $this->Users_obj[$user]->passWord == $pass) {
            delete_cache_full();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['log'] = true;
            $_SESSION['usergroup']=$this->Users_obj[$user]->level;
            $this->set_permission_session($_SESSION['usergroup']);
            include_once $config->path . 'config.php';
            $newUpdate2=showUpdates2();
            if(!empty($newUpdate2)){
                $_SESSION['updateremindlater']=$newUpdate2['date'];
                }
            //file  
            include_once $config->path . 'functions.php';
            $func = new UserFuncs();
            $func->validate();
            include_once $config->path  . 'view/ViewDashboard.php';
            return true;
        }
    }
```

thats the function im including this file into. `include_once $config->$path . 'functions.php';` includes functions.php file
functions.php looks like this

```
   include_once($path. "folder/config.php");
   echo($code);
```

and config.php looks like

```
  $code = "ERGERW2342HV3453WERWEER";
  $host_name = "SERV345WERFDGDDFGDGF";
  $return_code = "DFGDFSDGFS";
  $vurl = "YUIYUJHGJ";
  $next_val ="AWERFDFVDV";
  $val_exp = "NMGHJGJGH";
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to show your *complete* code for that to be answerable. Either your scope is wrong, or you're unsetting the variable or something else is being done which we can't determine from the snippet you show.

Comment: I think *deceze* is right, because the description your give is very hard to follow and it might be that you have an understanding problem which does not make it easy to describe the issue specifically. So best thing would be you share the whole code. Alternatively draw an image, that's probably even better: Visualize how includes are done. Also `include` and `include_once` do different things, so take care about the differences.

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($config->path);` to check that it contains what it should contain? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing PHP variables to an included file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601348/passing-php-variables-to-an-included-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing that you've `include`d config.php somewhere else before, and that it's not being included again due to `include_once`. Therefore the variables are not created in the scope you're including it in the second time.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a problem with variable scope, where you are trying t access the variable from somewhere (e.g. a function) where it is not available to that particular object (you did mention that you included the file within a class). 
I agree with deceze and hakre, it's very hard to answer this question without seeing your code.